# Perl Sorting Assistance

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement a bubble sort into my script that allows me to sort my data alphabetical.

```
**NetworkManager** Nov  8 13:24:23 osboxes <info> disable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes) NetworkManager[1249]:
**dhclient** Nov  8 15:52:45 osboxes DHCPOFFER of 192.168.253.129 from 192.168.253.254 dhclient:
**dhclient** Nov  8 15:52:45 osboxes DHCPACK of 192.168.253.129 from 192.168.253.254 dhclient:
**dnsmasq** Nov 13 17:52:35 osboxes using nameserver 192.168.253.2#53 dnsmasq[1637]:
```

This is what the file looks like, So read the file and then store it into an array.

I want to be able to sort the data alphabetical with whats at the start (in the ** **) so the output should look like:

```
**dhclient** Nov  8 15:52:45 osboxes DHCPOFFER of 192.168.253.129 from 192.168.253.254 dhclient:
**dhclient** Nov  8 15:52:45 osboxes DHCPACK of 192.168.253.129 from 192.168.253.254 dhclient:    
**dnsmasq** Nov 13 17:52:35 osboxes using nameserver 192.168.253.2#53 dnsmasq[1637]:
**NetworkManager** Nov  8 13:24:23 osboxes <info> disable requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes) NetworkManager[1249]:
```

Comment: Why bubble sort instead of just using perl's built-in `sort` function?  What have you got so far?

Comment: Maybe because the task says so? :)

Comment: I think the question posed by @Tanktalus is a valid one. Why not use the solution that requires almost zero work and probably has better performance?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to implement a bubble sort for this problem (is there ever?).

```
my @new_array = sort @original_array;
```

To make the sort case-insensitive:

```
my @new_array = sort {lc($a) cmp lc($b)} @original_array;
```

If you must use a bubble sort, [this](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#Perl) seems like a good reference, but the example is for arrays of numbers instead of strings. I would amend it to use string comparison operator `cmp`, similar to in the `sort` block above.

```
sub bubble_sort {
    for my $i (0 .. $#_){
        for my $j ($i + 1 .. $#_){
            my ($a,$b) = @_[$i, $j];

            # cmp returns -1 if the lefthand side is "less than" the right
            if ((lc($a) cmp lc($b)) == 1) {
                @_[$i, $j] = @_[$j, $i];
            }
        }
    }
}

bubble_sort(@array);
print "$_\n" for @array;
```

Comment: This answer will not sort lines in the order requested in the sample output.

Comment: True enough. OP first states they want alphabetical order, where traditionally capital letters come before lowercase. I had not noticed the desired output has capitalized strings after lowercase

Comment: There's not enough info here, but I suspect OP wants the sorting to be done case-insensitively.

Comment: edited. just one case insensitive bubble sort sub now

Comment: i've added your code and it works but only if i take out the ** ** is there a way to keep these in?

Comment: you actually don't need to use `substr` at all, as someone below pointed out. since the prefix "**" is always the same, you can just ignore it. I also edited an error in the bubble sort sub and tested on your example data. should work

Answer (score -1):

The best way how to do it is

```
LC_ALL=C sort -f
```

If you insist using Perl:

```
use autodie;
open my $fh, 'LC_ALL=C sort -f |';
print <$fh>;
```

Oh, you mean sort it inside in Perl:

```
use feature qw(fc);
print sort {fc $a cmp fc $b}, <>;
```

Or more efficient for bigger files:

```
use feature qw(fc);
print map $_->[0], sort {$a->[1] cmp $b->[1]} map [$_, fc], <>;
```

And note I don't have to do anything with `**` because they don't affect output order of your data.

Also, note I don't use `lc` or `uc` because it would not work correctly for all languages and using them instead of `fc` is a bad habit.

Comment: why is it a bad habit?

Comment: @beasy: Because neither `uc` nor `lc` is an answer to a question, how could I sort ignoring case. The answer is neither to convert it to the upper case nor to convert it to lower case. The answer is to convert it to case-folded representation which is exactly what `fc` is doing and doing it right. Doing things a wrong way when there is the right way is a bad habit. See `perldoc -f fc` for more details.

Comment: the real answer seems to be that `lc` and `uc` don't work for chars > 255. in ASCII range converting to lc or lc would be the same thing as casefolding. as someone who works with multiple languages, thx for pointing this out

Comment: @beasy It is not true `uc` nad `lc` definitely works for chars > 255. Try `perl -CO -Mutf8 -E'say uc "příliš žluťoučký kůň pěl ďábelské ódy"'`. The result should be `PŘÍLIŠ ŽLUŤOUČKÝ KŮŇ PĚL ĎÁBELSKÉ ÓDY` and it is in my `en_US.UTF-8` console.

Comment: That's what I said. I agree you should use `fc` for > 255, so you might as well just use it all the time for comparison